# List Comprehension to avoid multiple loop creation

Tags: python-3.x, list-comprehension

Can I avoid creating multiple loops for populating "c" as listed in the code below and instead shorten the length of the code? (Maybe through list comprehensions, or other means)

```
n,m = input().split()
a = [input().split() for i in range(0,int(n))]
b = [input().split() for i in range(0,int(m))]
c = []
for i in b:
    if i in a:
        c.append(list((y+1) for y, e in enumerate(a) if e == i))
else:c.append([-1])
for i in c:
    print(*i)
```

sample input --> ("5 2" and then separated lines)
5 2 
a
a
b
a
b
a
b

Comment: What do you pass in `input()`?

Comment: sample input: 
5 2
a
a
b
a
b
a
b

Comment: and what are you trying to do with the input?

Comment: Ascertain specific string positions where items from B have appeared in Array A -- so for eg: input of ("5 2" and then separated lines) 5 2 a a b a b a b  | output is 1 2 4 \n 3 5

Answer (score 0):

Shorter code but I'm not sure its easier to understand. Anyway, here it goes:

```
n,m = input().split()
A = [input().strip() for _ in range(int(n))]
B = [input().strip() for _ in range(int(m))]

C = [ [(idx + 1) for idx, s_B in enumerate(A) if s_B == s] if s in A else [-1] for s in B ]

for lst in C:
    print(*lst)
```